# Loop through json object and print results

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following json, and I want to loop through it and print out the error messages using jQuery.

Any help would be great. thanks!

```
var validationErrors = {"errors":["Please enter the month (1-12)","Please enter a day 1-31"]}
```

Edit, I know I have to use a loop, I'm just not sure really how to separate the error messages so I can print them out separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#error-container').append(
    '<p class="error">'
    + validationErrors.errors.join('</p><p class="error">') 
    + '</p>'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(validationErrors.errors).each(function() {
  $('#output').append($('<p>').text(this.toString())); //#output is where you want it printed
});
```

Comment: For some reason I was getting a jQuery error when I used this... but I got it working. Thanks